# Can I use automator to generate videos?

Tags: terminal, audio, video, automator

Let's say I have:

- A txt file
- A 1920x1080 image

I would like to generate a video [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v4uEvciMfs) where text is scrolling and audio is the output of the `say` command using automator (even a bash script is enough).

I was digging a bit with ffmpeg but with no success.

Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

Automator can help script other applications but it is not able to create new content alone, such as movies.

## Keynote and Other Alternatives

Have you considered using Apple's [Keynote](https://www.apple.com/it/keynote/)? Keynote can be used to create QuickTime movies involving [impressively complex motion](https://vimeo.com/129807396). Keynote supports AppleScript and can be automated.

Alternatively, the inexpensive and capable [Motion](https://www.apple.com/it/final-cut-pro/motion/) is worth trying.

A more technical approach would be [ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to create individual frames of the video and `ffmpeg` to [stitch the frames together](https://superuser.com/questions/624567/ffmpeg-create-a-video-from-images#624573) with music.

Comment: That's why I asked automator. I would like to make them even overnight, so I guess it's a bash script what I really need.

Comment: I have extended the answer to mention AppleScript and added `ImageMagik` as a third alternative.